# Time Series Analysis Python (for date & time)

Tags: python

I'm looking for other solutions on how to generate figures that can show time series analysis not only based on `date` but also together based on `time` because it's mission-critical.

Current code for histogram

```
histogram(df.date)

def histogram(df):
    plt.figure(figsize=(17, 5), edgecolor='blue')
    df.hist(grid=False, color='#86bf91')
```

Current code for the plot

```
df_cumulate = df.groupby(['date']).sum()
plot(df_cumulate, x=df_cumulate.index, y=df_cumulate.sentiment, title='Sentiment Over Time')
def plot(
    df,
    x,
    y,
    title='',
    xlabel='Date',
    ylabel='Sentiment',
    dpi=100,
    ):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 5), dpi=dpi)
    plt.plot(x, y, color='tab:red')
    plt.gca().set(title=title, xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel)
```

Dataset: https://gist.github.com/datomnurdin/33961755b306bc67e4121052ae87cfbc

Comment: You can try to use ```seaborn``` [Seaborn Lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) and [Seaborn distplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html). You can also use [Plotly](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-interactive-time-series-visualizations-with-plotly-in-python-d3219eb7a7af) which is interactive in a notebook and can probably send ready to use javascript to a front-end. If you are asking in general about "TIme Series visualization" there are plenty of articles on [Google](http://google.com/search?q=visualizing+time+series+python).

Comment: Plotly has zoom options as well that makes things convenient and pretty. :)

Comment: I see. I'm open to a new ideas as long also can zoom on time.

Comment: your linked dataset only has dates, no times?